# What is a more elegant way of reading a property of all elements of an array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

```
var data = [{"speed": 210},{"speed": 50},{"speed": 160}];
```

I want to get the maximum speed from `data`, so I am doing the following:

```
var max = Math.max(data[0]['speed'], data[1]['speed'], data[2]['speed']);
```

This is neither elegant or scalable (assume there could be an arbitrary amount of objects in the array).

NOTE: I have tagged jQuery as I have that on the page (i.e. if you can suggest a clever use of .grep or something it *is* available to me - although I'm assuming that's overkill?).

Comment: Your question and title don't seem to match. You don't need all the properties, you want one property of all the elements of an array.

Comment: Apologies, I'll edit accordingly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could map the objects `speed` properties into an array, and then use `Math.max` with `apply()` to get the largest number

```
Math.max.apply( null, data.map(function(x) {return x.speed}) );
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/gGpS7/)